# Using .htaccess to redirect non www to www including period after .co.uk

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule in my htaccess file, which I found suggested on a website (which I can no longer remember).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.example.co.uk)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I was testing the combinations to see how the redirect worked and these are the results

```
example.co.uk/foo/bar.html to www.example.co.uk/foo/bar.html
example.co.uk./foo/bar.html to www.example.co.uk/foo/bar.html
example.co.uk:80/foo/bar.html to www.example.co.uk/foo/bar.html
example.co.uk/ to www.example.co.uk
example.co.uk./ to www.example.co.uk
example.co.uk:80/ to www.example.co.uk
example.co.uk to www.example.co.uk
example.co.uk:80 to www.example.co.uk
```

The only one that failed to work was **`example.co.uk. to example.co.uk.`**

I am not sure how to change this condition to work with this this single scenario and would appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't it work if you just add the dot after example.co.uk with a ? afterwards? Like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.example.co.uk)?.?$ [NC]
```

Comment: I'll give it a go and get back to you

Comment: It seems to work for me when I change the rewritecond to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.co.uk [NC]` So it matches everything that doesn't start with www.example.co.uk that should also include the requests for example.co.uk. (with the dot at the end)